# Redirection with CSS and Javascript - handheld devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been trying to redirect based on screen size generically on all desktop and hand held devices and I guess media queries is quite an answer to it because when i detected screen size with javascript `screen.width` then different browsers returned me different screen size which was quite irritating that why is this happening. Well I need to know two things will the following code detect the screen as javascript did or it'll detect generically 100% accurate screen size? and if so how can i trigger a rediretion javascript code if the following css rule being becomes true?

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  /* iPhone, Android rules here */
}
```

Comment: It should be accurate, but that's always up to the browser though. Oh, by the way, you can't use JavaScript from CSS

Comment: @Alexander but Alas its not :( visit this url on your hand held and you'll notice this issue [link] http://radiations3.aiksite.com/home.html

Comment: Do your handheld's web browser supports media-queries? For this to work, it needs to

Comment: @Alexander Check out the following Url for detailed overview to screen detection issue for hand held devices http://tripleodeon.com/2011/12/first-understand-your-screen/

Answer (score 1):

You could use a framework like jQuery or Mootools to avoid browser inconsistencies.

I may have written something that does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/aUW4N/